# How to replace a string value based on JSON property names

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to replace values in a string with the comparable jSON property in an object.

```
var value = "/sessions/:sessionId/events/:id";
var result = replace(value, { sessionId : 1 , id : 23 });

// result : "/sessions/1/events/23"
console.log(result);
```

Is it possible with JavaScript (I'm sure it is)? Not sure about the most efficient way to do this and how to handle it when all the values inside the template string are not matched.

Thanks in advance.

### Update (Solution)

```
var url = function (template, parameters) {

    var extra = [];

    for (param in parameters) {
        if (value.indexOf(param) < 0) {
            extra.push(param + '=' + parameters[param]);
        }
    }

    var result = template.replace(/:(\w+)/g, function (substring, match) {
        var routeValue = parameters[match];
        if (!routeValue) {
            throw "missing route value for " + match + ' in "' + template +'"';
        }
        return routeValue;
    });

    if (result.indexOf("/:") > 0) {
        throw "not all route values were matched";
    }

    return (extra.length === 0) ? result : result + "?" + extra.join("&");
};

var value = "/sessions/:sessionId/events/:id";
var data = {
    sessionId: 1,
    id: 23,
    term: "butter"
};

// result : /sessions/1/events/21?term=butter
console.log(url(value, data));
```

Comment: That's *not* JSON.  It's a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that just so happens to very closely resemble JavaScript syntax.  It's *onlY* JSON if it's a string.  `{ sessionId : 1 , id : 23 }` is an object literal, `'{"sessionId": 1, "id": 23}'` (a string) is JSON.

Comment: The template url format is similar to AngularJs `$resource` url template, looking at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngResource/resource.js `setUrlParams()` does the magic and also handles url encoding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex would work just fine here.

```
var value = "/sessions/:sessionId/events/:id";
var obj = { sessionId : 1 , id : 23 };

var result = value.replace(/:(\w+)(\/|\b)/g, function(substring, match, nextMatch){
    return obj[match] + nextMatch;
});
```

Comment: is there a way to count how many of the values with the ":" were not matched? I'd like to throw an error if not all spots were replaced. I could probably just do a search for ":".

Comment: Also why match the "/" after the section? removing that still works.

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh: You could add an `if(!obj[match]){ failures++; }` in the callback.  I'm matching the `/`, because.... I don't know.  I guess you could remove it :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the following javascript object:

```
var myObject = { sessionId : 1 , id : 23 };
```

you can loop each property and do a replace on the original string...

```
var value = "/sessions/:sessionId/events/:id";

for(var item in myObject){
    value = value.replace(item, myObject[item]);
}

//value = "/sessions/:1/events/:23"
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/zwDjj/)

It is not clear if you want to keep the `:` characters or not. If not, then you can just include that in your replace function:

```
value = value.replace(':' + item, myObject[item]);
```

---

**Checking for missing parameters**

If you have any extra values in your object that do not exist in your input string, then they will not have any effect. If however, you want to take action if one of the items is not found in the original string, then you can do a check in the loop:

```
var noMatch = false;
for(var item in myObject){
    if(value.indexOf(item) < 0){
        noMatch = true;
    }
    value = value.replace(item, myObject[item]);
}
if(noMatch){
    //something is wrong!
}
```

---

**Dealing with JSON**

If you *do* actually have a JSON string to begin with, you can convert that to an object with the following:

```
var jsonString = '{"sessionId": 1, "id": 23}';
var myObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: thanks musefan, I really liked this answer too, but I liked the simplicity of the other one as well.

Comment: @KhalidAbuhakmeh: Personally I think my solution is more simple. Mine is also [much more efficient](http://jsperf.com/replace-v-loop)

Comment: yeah you make a good point, I'll probably tweak it. I wish I could give both of you the checkmark. StackOverflow needs a split bounty.

Answer (score 1):

here is another way of doing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/rayweb_on/suHej/

```
 var value = "/sessions/:sessionId/events/:id";
 var source = { sessionId : 1 , id : 23 };
 var result = value.replace(":sessionId",source.sessionId);
 var result = result.replace(":id",source.id);
 console.log(result);
```